# Automatically Update Database Fields when the date in other field is reached

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want the database to automatically update my auction status "In process" to "true" when start date is reached and to "false" when auction end date has expired.

Currently I am using timer finish callback to update the database. But the problem with this approach is that this will only update database when a user visits the page.

I am looking for application level solutions.

Is this the correct way? If not what is the possible solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try onUpdate trigger?

Comment: Maybe a job in the sql agent ?

Comment: I was looking for implementation in asp.net mvc